# How to hide a picture box on another Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

To elaborate on the title:

I currently have 2 forms.

- Form1 = Main form
- Form2 = linked to Form1 using `ShowDialog()`

Form1 has 3 picture boxes and a button

Form2 is a simple Fillable form and what I want it to do is when I click the OK button on Form2, I have form2 set to close But I need to hide the picture boxes and buttons on Form1, i.e. have it show blank.

I'm not too sure what I am doing wrong.

I added the picture boxes as public declaration in Form2.vba

```
Public Class CreateNewProject

'declare Form1 objects
Public Img_Documentation As PictureBox
Public Img_OnlineResources As PictureBox
Public Img_Tutorials As PictureBox
```

And I added the `.hide()` to each picture box in my button sub

```
Private Sub ButtonOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonOK.Click

    If TextNewProjectName.Text = "" And TextSaveFileLocation.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a " & LabelProjectFileName.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please choose a " & LabelSaveFileLocation.Text, "Warning")
    Else
        'Close current form
        Me.Close()
        'Close objects on Form1
        Img_Documentation.Hide()
        Img_OnlineResources.Hide()
        Img_Tutorials.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively, I tried creating a new blank form (form3) opening that form after closing form2 which worked great but I cannot get Form1 to close using `Form1.close()`.

```
 Me.Close()
 Form3.Show()
 Form1.close()
```

Comment: There should be no code at all in `Form2` that refers to `Form1`.  When `Form1` calls `ShowDialog`, it will block until `Form2` closes.  That means that you simply add your code to hide your controls after the `ShowDialog` call.  If `Form1` needs data from `Form2` to know exactly hwat to do then you add public properties in `Form2` to expose that data and `Form1` retrieves it.  `Form1` does the work for itself and `Form2` doesn't even know that `Form1` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply hide the `PictureBox` on your `Form1` Before you open `Form2`:

```
PictureBox1.Visible = False
PictureBox2.Visible = False
PictureBox3.Visible = False
Form2.Show()
```

Comment: @Nix remember to mark it as answer if this solved your problem